# How can we conclude that $\mathbb{P}(A)\leq \mathbb{P}(B)?$

Tags: probability

Given two events $A$ and $B$, if the event $A$ happens, then $B$ happens. How can we conclude that 
$$\mathbb{P}(A)\leq \mathbb{P}(B)?$$

Comment: Regarding $A,B$ as subsets of the ambient space, this is just monotonicity of the probability measure.

Comment: @Dave I am a little confused with $A\subset B$...?

Comment: Have you ever seen events represented as Venn diagrams? If yes, then I have a helpful answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"if A happens then B happens" means that

$A \subseteq B$, that imply also $\mathbb{P}[A] \leq \mathbb{P}[B]$

Comment: This is just a restatement of the problem

Comment: @TheoC. +1; no it’s not. The original problem never said $A\subseteq B$. tommik is concluding that, and accurately so

Answer (score 0):

Assume we make the following bet: You give me $P(A)$ dollars, and then if $A$ happens, then I give you $1$ dollar. This clearly is a fair bet.

Also, we make another bet: I give you $P(B)$ dollars, and then if $B$ happens, then you give me $1$ dollar. Again, this is a fair bet.

Obviously two fair bets made at the same time should still be fair.

Now assume $P(A)>P(B)$. Since at the beginning, You give me $P(A)$ dollars and I give you $P(B)$ dollars, effectively you give me $P(A)-P(B)$ dollars, which is a positive quantity.

Now let's look at the outcomes. If neither $A$ nor $B$ happens, neither of us wins a dollar, so in total I've gotten $P(A)-P(B)$ dollars from you. If $A$ does not happen, but $B$ does, then I don't give you a dollar, but you give me one, so in total I get $P(A)-P(B)+1$ dollars. Finally, if $A$ happens, then by assumption $B$ happens as well, therefore each of us owes the other one dollar, which means again I end with a total win of $P(A)-P(B)$.

So in short, no matter what happens, I will always come out with at least $P(A)-P(B)$ dollars net win. This clearly is a Dutch book, not a fair bet.

Since valid probability distributions don't allow Dutch books, we therefore have to conclude that $P(A)\le P(B)$

Comment: What’s a Dutch book?

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_book